# Product of countably many 1-dimensional spaces does not have cardinality $\aleph_0$

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

From Bergman's "Universal Algebra: Fundamentals and Selected Topics" page 52, constructing a directly indecomposable algebra (one which does not admit a decomposition into directly indecomposable components): (note: $\omega := \mathbb N$)

> But consider a space $\mathbf V$ with basis $\{\,v_i:i\in\omega\,\}$. [...] But $\mathbf V$ is also not the product of infinitely many 1-dimensional spaces. The reason is that $\mathbf V$ has cardinality $\aleph_0$ while, based on a standard set-theoretic argument, the product can not have cardinality $\aleph_0$. Thus $\mathbf V$ has no decomposition into directly indecomposable components.

Anyone care to enlighten me on this "standard set-theoretic argument"? I don't believe I've seen this one before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of countably infinitely many copies of $\mathbb F_2$, say, can be identified with the set of functions $\omega\to \mathbb F_2$, or with the power set of $\omega$, or with $\mathbb R$. At any rate it has $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0$ elements. Note that the *direct sum* of countably many copies of $\mathbb F_2$ would be countable though (corresponding only to the set of finite subsets of $\omega$)

Comment: Goodness, I've lived my whole life not realizing there was a difference between direct sum and direct product. Silly me.